# Does the parent attribute of bean tag is equivalent to inheritance in Java?

Tags: java, spring

I started studying Spring documentation. I came across `parent` attribute explanation, does using `parent` attribute between two beans is equivalent to inheritance relationship between these classes?

If so, how to perform method overriding? Also I saw in some context, use of both `parent` attribute in XML config file and `extends` keyword in bean class. Is it required to specify both springs in order to implement inheritance?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-child-bean-definitions explains it all.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- In spring, the `parent` in bean configuration signifies `configuration inheritance` and not related to Java inheritance.
- The `configuration inheritance` saves a lot of code as you do away with repeated XML code.

For example, you have following bean with attributes

```
Class MyBean {
    attrib1
    attrib2
    attrib3
    attrib4
}
```

Say one instance of bean say `bean1` just needs `attrib1` and `attrib2` whereas another say `bean2` instance needs all four the attributes.

Lets configure these two beans

```
<bean id="bean1" class="MyBean">
    <property name="attrib1" value="val1" />
    <property name="attrib2" value="val2" />
</bean>

<bean id="bean2" parent="bean1">
    <property name="attrib3" value="val3" />
    <property name="attrib4" value="val4" />
</bean>
```

Note that `bean2` just needed to configure `attrib3` and `attrib4`. The other two attributes are **inherited** from `bean1`

To answer your question:

> Does it is required to specify both springs in order to implement
>   inheritance?

No. As mentioned earlier this is not the same as java inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Santosh.But now i noticed one point from the below link mentioned by Deinum that "A child bean definition inherits constructor argument values, property values, and method overrides from the parent, with the option to add new values".  So, using parent attribute supports method overriding?

Comment: As I mentioned, there is no connection between `parent` attribute in spring config and Java inheritance and hence method overriding. The configured bean will have all the method(including inherited, overridden) irrespective of whether that bean has parent attribute defined or not.

Answer (score 6):

No... They aren't related to each other.

A parent bean definition can be considered a form of template for other beans (which don't have to have any relationship). Imagine you have 3 beans which all share/need a username/password/url configuration you can then create a parent bean which defines all these properties. This reduces your configuration effort (you don't have to duplicate the properties in all the bean definitions).

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions gives a nice overview.